# Cometd Compatible with jetty 8.1.11

Tags: java, jetty, comet, cometd, jetty-8

I am currently working on a project using cometd 1.0.0 and jetty 8.1.11.

I was getting the following exception: 
`WARN:oejut.Timeout:EXCEPTION
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.util.LazyList.removeFromArray([Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.cometd.server.ClientImpl.removeSubscription(ClientImpl.java:495)
        at org.cometd.server.ChannelImpl.unsubscribe(ChannelImpl.java:339)
        at org.cometd.server.ClientImpl.unsubscribeAll(ClientImpl.java:527)
        at org.cometd.server.AbstractBayeux.removeClient(AbstractBayeux.java:526)
        at org.cometd.server.ClientImpl.remove(ClientImpl.java:370)
        at org.cometd.server.continuation.ContinuationClient.remove(ContinuationClient.java:220)
        at org.cometd.server.continuation.ContinuationClient$1.expired(ContinuationClient.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Timeout.tick(Timeout.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Timeout.tick(Timeout.java:153)
        at org.cometd.server.continuation.ContinuationBayeux$1.run(ContinuationBayeux.java:76)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)`

When i updated cometd to version 1.1.5, i cannot see this error anymore. but my cpu usage for jetty is quite high on load testing.

Can anyone suggest a stable version of cometd that is compatible with jetty 8.1.11.

Answer (score 3):

CometD 1.x is not maintained anymore; CometD 2.x is out since July 2010.

I strongly recommend you to upgrade to CometD 2.x (current version `2.7.0`), which will work fine with every Jetty 8 version, although I recommend you to use the latest Jetty 8, currently `8.1.14.v20131031`.

Comment: thanks, i agree that i should upgrade to latest, but i wanted a temporary solution for now, as i am planning to upgrade to jetty 9 and cometd 3 and waiting for build of cometd 3.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the information on Maven Central, it appears that the first time Jetty8 is used by cometd itself first shows up in [the metadata for Cometd 2.7.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.cometd%7Ccometd-project%7C2.7.0%7Cpom).

However, it lists version `8.1.13.v20130916` as the one it uses itself, not version 8.1.11.

*For completeness sake, here's [the metadata for Cometd 2.6.0](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.cometd%7Ccometd-project%7C2.6.0%7Cpom), notice it has no jetty8 reference.*

Comment: Thanks, So you mean i should upgrade to **jetty 8.1.13.v20130916** and **cometd 2.7.0**, and as the other versions might cause compatibility issues ?